# Angular Material md-menu Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, menu, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material and when I put a md-menu inside my app, an error is showed. This is the error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
```

Code:

```
<md-menu>
   <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Open sample menu">
       <md-icon md-svg-icon="call:phone"></md-icon>
   </md-button>
   <md-menu-content>
       <md-menu-item>
            <md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button>
       </md-menu-item>
   </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

I'm using bower and the error start to appear when I uploaded the version of angular material **from 0.11.0 to 1.0.1.** This is my bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "Angular-Base",
    "dependencies": {
    "angucomplete-alt": "~1.1.0",
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.3",
    "angular-aria": "~1.4.3",
    "angular-chart.js": "~0.7.2",
    "angular-drag-and-drop-lists": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-emoji": "~0.1.0",
    "angular-emoji-filter-hd": "~0.0.6",
    "angular-material": "1.0.1",
    "angular-md5": "~0.1.8",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
    "hint.css": "~1.3.5",
    "jquery-legacy": "jquery#1.11.3",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "ng-file-upload": "~6.2.1",
    "ngWYSIWYG": "*",
    "angular-material-data-table": "0.9.7",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "~0.6.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-translate": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.7.2"
},
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.3"
}
```

Also I read and test [this question](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3258) without success...

Mention that **everything is right** and works in the menu (clicks actions are good too), but that error appears in console everytime I put an md-menu... so I want to fix that...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need $mdOpenMenu? Try to repeat 1.0.1 version of md-menu example. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVqBeb

Comment: You should first make sure that all your angular libs have the same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! :)

I was using a gulp task (gulp-minify-html node module) to process html and this module insert the string 'data' before all angular tags. So in my code I didn't see that prefix but the code that was generated has it.

So finally, [this question](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3258) has the answer.